# Fundamental group of two topological spaces joined with a straight line

Tags: algebraic-topology

Suppose that two topological spaces $X$ and $Y$ are given and they are joined each other with a straight line. We call $Z$ the resulting topological space. Which is the fundamental group?

Well, I want to use Van Kampen theorem. If I take as open set $A=X \cup T_1$, where $T_1$ is an open interval of the straight line and $B=Y \cup T_2$, where $T_2$ is another open interval of the straight line intersecting $T_1$, may I conclude that the first open retracts to $X$ while the second to $Y$ and, since $A \cap B$ is simply connected, then $\pi_1(Z)=\pi_1(X) * \pi_1(Y)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct. Notice that you can contract the line so you get the wedge sum $X \vee Y$, and with Van-Kampen again you can see that $\pi_1( X \vee Y) \cong \pi_1(X) * \pi_1(Y)$.